# React and redux, modular editing of object hierarchy and REST api

Tags: javascript, rest, design-patterns, reactjs, redux

I have `Foo` object which has an array of `Bars`. They are separate tables in database and both of them are individual REST api resources.

```
{
  id: 1,
  data: foo,
  bars: [
    { fooId: 1, data: bar1 },
    { fooId: 2, data: bar2 }
  ]
}
```

I want to create form like editor which let's me view, edit, add and remove *Bar's* of the particular *Foo*. I figured out I would nest *BarsComponent* in *FooComponent*, and further *BarComponent* to hold reference to individual Bar. This component should draw two way bound input box and delete button for *Bar prop*. *BarsComponent* should also render *add button*. There will be multiple children like Bars.

The problem is that save button is in *FooComponent*, so somehow I must know at the moment of click what changed and where to dispatch right *Redux actions* with particular domain object. The complexity comes from user being able to do all CRUD operations in arbitrary child components, and I need that information at upper level.

What is approved way to manage this complexity? Would it be fine to create a *Redux state* for changes, and scan that state in save click handler and dispatch found changes?

Comment: IMHO you should not scan for states when needed, instead children should notify parent each time their inner state changes through a callback. Then the parent always got the information it needs to send the 'save' request

Answer (score 0):

Your *FooComponent* should have a function that it passes to each of the *BarComponents* that it creates. The *BarComponents* call that function when any data changes which allows the *FooComponent* to hold and manage all the changes and push the changes back down into the *BarComponent* through its props.

For example, if the *BarComponent* has several input boxes then each of these has its onChange event set to the function that was passed down from *FooComponent* which holds and manages the changed data.

Something else that you might want to consider is how you're holding the data in Redux. Instead of a Foo object (or collection of Foo objects) with Bar objects in an array you might want to keep each Bar object in a parent Bar object with the key as the id. For example:

```
Bar {
  '1': {
    name: 'John'
  },
  '2': {
    name: 'Sally'
  }
}
```

And the Foo object would have an array of Ids that mapped to the keys in this object. This would closely resemble what the server side database has and might make your management of the data in redux/react easier.

There is one disadvantage that I've found with this though that you should be aware of. I have a reducer for each of the objects so they know nothing about the other. This seems to be common (good) redux practice. So one thing that I can't do is sort the array of Ids (by date for example) in the reducer and I usually end up having to push this down to the component that renders the array. This does sometimes have an advantage because on occasion I'll end up filtering the array and so the sort is working on fewer elements.